# Inductive Charging Mouse

Tags: battery-charging, inductive, diy, wireless-charging

I recently bought a [wireless gaming mouse](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-gb/product/g700s-rechargeable-wireless-gaming-mouse) and while functionally its great, the battery life is a little less than I would like.

I tried to mitigate this by adding in another rechargable AA battery (as the bay only fits one) but found this wouldn't be possible without grinding away some of the internal plastic, which I'm not prepared to do.

Therefore, I came up with the idea of fitting an induction charging coil within the mouse, with a charger embedded in a custom-built mousemat.

Ideally I would have liked to have made the mat out of aluminium, but after looking into it it seems this would result in interference, preventing proper charging.

What other factors like this are there that I should be aware of going forward with this project?

I'm intending on powering the charger via USB from my PC, would there be current/voltage concerns connecting this? How about in the connection between the receiver coil and the battery within the mouse?

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to things like this, so any and all guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1459

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/products/2115 or just stick the uUSB cable. That's why I never had a wireless mouse.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to do everything from scratch or rather use a prebuilt set that you just need to hook up?

If you want to build from scratch take a look at [**this guide from 2007**](http://www.discovercircuits.com/dc-mag/Issue-1/issue%201-pg-4.htm)

If you want to use a prebuilt set (recommended) something like this could work:
[**Seeed studio wireless power supply**](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/wireless-power-supply-p-701.html?cPath=155)

or from [**Adafruit product 1459**](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1459), as mentioned in the comments above.

[image]

but again consider that the 3.3V you get from the receiving coil can not be used directly to charge your battery, otherwise it will get killed, heat up or catch fire eventually.

But closely take care of exactly how you charge your battery. NiMH and Lithium batteries require different charging voltages and currents. You have to add the correct charging device between the receiving coils voltage output and your battery. Just hooking up the 5V output of the receiving coil will destroy your battery and mouse!
Possibilities for NiMH batteries would be using a BQ2002 chip from TI:  Here you would have to make a small circuit board.

Or if you are using a Lithium rechargeable battery a small prebuilt charger like this would do: 
From sparkfun: product 11231  (sorry i can only post 2 links, so please google the product)
From adafruit: product 1944 (sorry i can only post 2 links, so please google the product)